# How to turn off shutter sound on LG G5?

Tags: audio, camera, do-not-disturb, camera-sound

How to turn off shutter sound on LG G5 with latest official firmware (Android 7)? "Do not disturb" sound mode does not working for shutter sound.

Comment: Put your ringtone in silent or vibration and try taking a picture

Comment: This also does not help. Model F700S (Korean, can't be rooted).

Answer (score 0):

Phones with a Korean SIM, or sometimes Korean phones with any SIM, do not allow the user to turn off the shutter sound for legal reasons. I don't think there's any reasonable way around this.